# How to make files created in a directory owned by directory owner?

Tags: linux, file-permissions

Is there any method on Linux to effect all new files created in a directory to be owned by the directory's owner instead of the creating user's owner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use chmod to achieve this.

`chmod g+s YourDirectory`

With this command. all files which are created in this directory, will be owned by the directory-group.

Comment: i didnt mean directory's group, i exactly mean that owned by directory's **OWNER**

Answer (score 0):

I would create a bash/shell script that can create new directories in the folder with that owner as the owner.

Then add the users to a group that have execute permissions for the shell script.